# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 42040, 512), found shape=(None, 512)

Tags: keras

I can not identify the error. Can you help!! Please!!!

```
from torch.nn.modules import activation
from tensorflow.keras import models
from keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import add
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input

from torch import relu

input_shape = en_X_train.shape[1]
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()


input_shape = en_X_train.shape

modeloA = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

modeloA.add(keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape))
modeloA.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
modeloA.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
modeloA.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
modeloA.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='linear'))
modeloA.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
modeloA.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
modeloA.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
modeloA.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

modeloA.summary()
modeloA.layers[2].trainable = False
modeloA.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=-0.075),
            metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
HistA = modeloA.fit(en_X_train, en_y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=25, verbose=1)
```

Model: "sequential"

---

## Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #

batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 42040, 512)       2048
ormalization)

dense (Dense)               (None, 42040, 256)        131328

dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 42040, 256)        65792

dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 42040, 128)        32896

batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 42040, 128)       512
hNormalization)

activation (Activation)     (None, 42040, 128)        0

dropout (Dropout)           (None, 42040, 128)        0

dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 42040, 1)          129

=================================================================
Total params: 232,705
Trainable params: 231,425
Non-trainable params: 1,280

---

### Epoch 1/25

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
33                         optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=-0.075),
34             metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision(), tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
---> 35 HistA = modeloA.fit(en_X_train, en_y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=25, verbose=1)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16                 except:
17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 889, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" is '

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 42040, 512), found shape=(None, 512)
```

Can you help!!!!Please!!!!

Comment: Maybe remove this line `input_shape = en_X_train.shape`

Comment: Sorry, but where did you define `en_X_train`?